# conjugated subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having trouble understanding the following concept of conjugation.

Let $G=P \ltimes Q$ be a finite group, where $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$ and $Q \in {\rm Syl}_q(G)$.
Let $P_1, P_2$ be two subgroups of $P$ which are conjugate in $G$ i.e. 
$g^{-1}{P_1}g={P_1}^g={P_2}$, where $g \in G$. I want to know why $P_1,P_2$ are conjugate in $P$.

Comment: Did you notice that there exist subgroups $\hat{P}_i\leq G$ s.t. $\hat{P}_i/Q\cong P_i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answer was to an earlier version of the question.

Let $G = P \ltimes Q$.

*Lemma* If $a \in P$, $b \in Q$, and $a^b (=b^{-1}ab) \in P$ then $a^b=a$.

*Proof*. $[a,b] = a^{-1}b^{-1}ab \in P \cap Q = 1$, so $a^b=a$.

Now let $P_1,P_2 \le P$ and $P_1^g=P_2$ with $g \in G$. We can write $g=ab$ with $a \in P,b \in Q$. Then $P_1^a \le P$ and $P_1^{ab} = P_2 \le P$, so by the lemma $P_1^g = P_1^{ab} = P_1^a = P_2$, and $P_1$ and $P_2$ are conjugate in $P$.

Comment: Thank you so so much.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true in general. Let $G = A_4 \times C_2 \times C_2$ (of order $48$), and let $Q = A_4$ be the first factor. Let $P$ be the subgroup of $Q$ of order $4$. Then $P \cong C_2 \times C_2 \cong G/Q$.

Now if we take $P_1$ and $P_2$ to be two subgroups of order $2$ in $P$, then they are conjugate in $Q$ and hence in $G$, but not conjugate in $P$.

Comment: Is it true that ${P_1}^{Qg}=P_2$?

Comment: I don't believe that there is any standard definition of $H^A$ for a subgroup $H$ and a subset $A$ of a group $G$. I guess you could define $H^A = \langle H^a : a \in A \rangle$. But however you define it the answer is no. We can take  $g \in Q$, so $P_1^{Qg} = P_1^Q = P$.

Comment: Moreover if $G=P \ltimes Q$, can i say anything?

Comment: Yes if $G = P \ltimes Q$ then two subgroups of $P$ that are conjugate in $P$ are conjugate in $G$.

Comment: that is if $G=P \ltimes Q$, can i say that ${P_1}^{Qg}=P_2$? sorry for question, i need to understand this concept.

Comment: I don't really understand what $P_1^{Qg}$ means. Since $Qg$ is an element of $G/Q$ it is possible that it should be $(P_1Q/Q)^{Qg} = P_2Q/Q$, which is correct in $G/Q$. Of course by the second isomorphism theorem we have $P_1Q/Q \cong P_1/P_1\cap Q \cong P_1$ and $P_2Q/Q \cong P_2$.

Comment: yes thanks, as a final question(im so sorry for my questions), if $G=P \ltimes Q$, and $P_1,P_2$ are conjugate in $G$, then can we conclude that $P_1,P_2$ are conjugate in $P$? i want to show it.

Comment: You said that if $P_1,P_2$ are conjugate in $P$, then they Are conjugate in $G$.

Comment: indeed, you said that if ${P_1}^a=P_2$, then ${P_1}^g=P_2$, for some $g \in G$.($a \in P$). But i dont understand it

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right! I wrote the wrong thing last time. I meant to write that if  $G = P \ltimes G$ and two subgroups of $P$ are conjugate in $G$, then they are conjugate in $P$. Please edit your question and ask the new question.

Comment: i edited my question.